# Using Ant to write to a property file to be used in JAVA

Tags: java, unit-testing, ant, properties, arguments

**Requirement** : I need to pass user details to my JUnit tests using Ant build file.

**Limitation** : It's a large project with a number of build files and I'm not allowed to change much and so, passing the properties as JUnit arg is not an option.

**Alternative** : Pass the parameters as Ant arguments, write them in a property file and read it in my tests.

Since the Java property file is updated during runtime, I won't be able to access the resource object in a static way as below:

```
Class A {
  private static Resources ab = new Resources(A.class);

  public static getResourceString(String id) {
    return ab.getResourceString(id);
  }
}
```

In my tests, accessing using `A.getResourceString("user1");`

I think, I'll need to use something like `new A().getResourceString(id);` after making the resource `ab` not static.

But this does not seem to be the perfect way (assuming this will work). Is there any flaw with the above argument? Is there any other alternative?

Note: sending parameters as Java or Junit arg is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

Push back - your unit tests shouldn't take any input.  Think of them as scientific experiments, with *one* variable (the code) - everything else should be static.  In the scheme you describe the tests could fail due to an incorrect or unexpected input.  Unit test failures should mean an error in the code.

I don't mean to say these tests don't have value - but they're not unit tests.

Comment: i need to pass in the users with which they'll run. I cannot hard code it in a property file since they will be running simultaneously at different machines and using same users do lead to some issues.

Comment: I get it, my point is you should rework your tests so they can't fail due to issues such as multiple test runs happening on the same machine.